# Ajax http request from Pebble to Raspberry Pi Python server fails

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cloudpebble

As a Pebble/Ajax/Java Script/Python newbie I am working on the very basic code in order to receive Raspberry Pi sensor readings on the Pebble watch:

I am executing a simple Ajax request from Pebble to a Raspberry Pi Python server but fail to get a any reponse (Client/Server code is below).

However, the Raspberry server is responding sucessfully when I open a web browser and and enter the local url to the Raspberry Pi, ex. 192.168.1.80:9999: 
{"Pi response":"Hello World!}"

Also the Pebble reponse is successful when I change the local URL from 192.168.1.80 to a very simple php-script on a remote web page (http://if.christianbirch.dk/helloworld.php):
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: {"Web response":"Hello World!"}

I've searched through many forums for a solution but without luck. However, I suspect that either the local URL or port number is somehow incorrectly defined in the Ajax script - or the Raspberry Pi Python script could be missing a header sentence.

Any experience re. this issue? Thank you in advance!

---

The Pebble JS script:

---

```
var ajax = require('ajax');

ajax(
{
url: 'http://192.168.1.80', // *** Valid reponse is received when changing this URL to http://if.christianbirch.dk/helloworld.php ***
method: 'get',
type: 'json',
port:'9999'
},
function(data) {
// Success!
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
},
function(error) {
// Failure!
console.log('No response!');
}
);
```

---

The Python server script (Valid reponse received when called from web browser)
https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html

---

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
 def handle(self):
   self.reqdata = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
   print self.reqdata
   self.send('{"Pi Reponse":"Hello world!"}')
 def send(self.content):
   self.request.sendall('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n{}.format(content))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 9999
  server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
  server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Is the `pebble` also on the local (192.168.1.x) network when it fails to get a response from the pi?

Comment: question 2 - what is the 'ajax' library you are using?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for your quick response. Due to your very simple question I am realizing that the Pebble development tool is cloud-based, not registring local IP addresses. I'll attempt downloading the Pebble SDK to a local device and retry the attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have figured out, in CloudPebble, the web-based emulator does not have local network access. To use CloudPebble along with local network app development, you need to set your Phone to be the compilation target. I ran into this as well while also developing against my Pi.